# autocomplete code in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

i have area list in alphabet wise, i want to display it when i enter first letter in my textbox. Autocomplete code in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use AJAX Autocomplete
http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is an option, you could take a look at the [Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

[Have a look at this](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) AjaxControlToolkit:AutoComplete Extender is another option

Answer (score 1):

If Silverlight is one of your options, then it will be a cake job:

Xaml:

```
<input:AutoCompleteBox x:name="myAutoCompleteBox"></input:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Code behind,

```
myAutoComplete.ItemsSource = "a b d e f g".Split(' ');
```

You can bind other events `TextChanged()`, `SelectionChanged()`, or do custom value bindings, custom filtermode.